# GCM notification in php

Tags: php, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send gcm notification using PHP as server side language. I am unable to send gcm notification to large number of users, e.g. 3000 to 10000.

When I tested it for 1 or up to 10 users then it works.

Comment: I think gcm has limit on sending push to devices, you can buy plans on cloud pushing such as parse, pushwoosh, etc

Answer (score 0):

GCM has limit for reg_ids;

> Though for general purposes it is deprecated, you can use registration_ids as a target for multicast messages to more than one device (up to 1000).

You can give your reg_ids number and parse with mod = 10.

And send 10 thread which is using

- regid % 10 = 1;
- regid % 10 = 2;
- ...
- ...
- regid % 10 = 0;

This is the fastest way to it. But in php thread methods are not usefull! I suggest use more efficent language for send GCM. (Java, Phyton etc.).

Example;

```
begin
    //get regids which mod 10 equals threadNumber
    array = getRegids(threadNumber);
    foreach(sendingArray : parseArray1000(array))
        sendGCM(sendingArray);
        // remove array for unexpected errors.
        remove(sendingArray);
finish
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the same push notification to bunch of users using the "Notification Key" of GCM
Create the notification key for the first time using first GCM key then add the further GCM ids to that notification key...
Sending notification key to notification key will send the notification to all devices.

For more info go through the following link
https://medium.com/appunite-edu-collection/notifications-d7df385b0ff4

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_chunk to breakdown GCM id arrays into multiple parts.

```
<?php
$input_array = array('GCMID1', 'GCMID2', 'GCMID3', 'GCMID4', 'GCMID5');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));

?>
```

And then loop through chunked array and send notification.